# ios: Vertical position is ambiguous for UIPageControl

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, ambiguity

I have a `UIPageControl` as a subview of a `UICollectionView`. Here are the constraints for the `UICollectionView`:

```
let collectionViewConstraints = [
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.65),
        collectionView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor)
    ]

collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(collectionViewConstraints)
```

Constraints for the `UIPageControl` are:

```
collectionView.addSubview(pageControl)
let pageControlConstraints = [
        pageControl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        pageControl.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.bottomAnchor, constant: 100)
    ]

pageControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(pageControlConstraints)
```

Since `pageControl` has `intrinsicContentSize`, I only specify its x and y positions. However, I encounter an ambiguous layout error for the vertical position of `pageControl`.

[image]

As shown in the first screenshot, the `pageControl` doesn't seem to get pinned to the bottom of `collectionView`. When debugging the view hierarchy, it seems that the bottom edge of `pageControl` is laid out in respect to the bottom edge of `collectionView`, yet the distance between the two seems much larger than what I specified (100).

[image]
[image]

I'm not sure what causes this ambiguous layout since I believe I have specified all the necessary constraints for `pageControl`. I would appreciate any feedback.

Note: the ambiguity goes away if I constrain `pageControl` to `collectionView.topAnchor` instead of `collectionView.bottomAnchor`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `UIPageControl` to `viewController`'s `view`.

Replace

```
collectionView.addSubview(pageControl)
```

With

```
self.view.addSubview(pageControl)
```